# Escapting special chars in Codename One string

Tags: codenameone

I am extracting data from a file and inserting it into an sqlite db.

Everything works fine until the data has special characters.

E.g. when I try an insert a url it fails because of the '//'

Or ... when I try and install "I'll" it fails on the "'"

( at the moment I am using the REPLACE function as a workaround - but this has its own problems )

Please advise how I might escape these characters?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the version of the SQL query that accepts a params argument and using that as it doesn't require escaping. If you use single quotes `'` to enclose your data you won't need escaping for most characters.

Comment: I am not sure that I follow - here is my code

db = Display.getInstance().openOrCreate("myDb.db");
String sqlStringRaw = "insert into myTable(col1, col2) values ('" + col1Val + "','" + col2Val + "')";                                                            
db.execute(sqlStringRaw); 

As you can see I am using a parameterised string and I am wrapping the whole thing in quotes.

Debug output:
sqlStringRaw = (java.lang.String) "insert into myTable(col1, col2) values ('2b8575df5','My API's')"

Here is the error
... [near "s": syntax error: ]

Comment: Try `String sqlStringRaw = "insert into myTable(col1, col2) values (?,?)"; ` and then `db.execute(sqlStringRaw, new String[] {col1Val, col2Val}); `